# SQL nested WHERE

Tags: sql

Currently my query looks like so:

```
SELECT start_date, from_id, to_id, from_amount, to_amount
FROM sample_table
WHERE from_id = '123'
OR to_id = '123';
```

However, what I'm really aiming for is one `amount` column in my results which shows `from_amount` WHERE `from_id = 123` and `to_amount` WHERE `to_id = 123`.

So instead of:

```
start_date / from_id / to_id / from_amount / to_amount
2016-01-01 /  '123'  / '456' /     100     /    20
2016-01-07 /  '789'  / '123' /      50     /    75
```

I'd like to return:

```
start_date / amount
2016-01-01 /  100
2016-01-07 /  75
```

I'm assuming I need to use some sort of nested WHERE, but not sure how to set it up.

Comment: You just need a CASE expression.. `SELECT CASE WHEN from_id = 123 THEN from_amount WHEN to_id = 123 THEN to_amount END AS Amount`

Comment: @JamieD77: Post as an answer ... ;) (your solution > union all, IMHO) ;)

Comment: @Ditto: No you are wrong, this  `Case when` doesn't handle the case when `from_id=123` and `to_id=123`.

Comment: @haytem: fair enough ... let the OP clarify the logistics of that. Looking at name of columns, I'm guessing, however, that's a side case we don't need to handle :)  But in the general case, you are absolutely correct, good point. :)

Comment: @haytem, @Ditto, actually in this specific case `from_id` can never equal `to_id` so that's not a concern.

Comment: @Ditto: I tried to give a general solution without any information about the content of this table, but you are also right, `case` can be quicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT start_date, from_amount AS amount
FROM Sample_table
WHERE from_id = '123'
UNION ALL
SELECT start_date, to_amount AS amount
FROM Sample_table
WHERE to_id = '123'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNION ALL

```
SELECT start_date, from_amount
FROM sample_table
WHERE from_id = 123
UNION ALL
SELECT start_date, to_amount
FROM sample_table
WHERE to_id = 123
```